# Microsoft SQL Server 2005 cast date/time to string

Tags: sql-server, casting

How can I convert @lastEndTime to a string formated `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MS`?

```
DECLARE @lastEndTime datetime
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CONVERT(nvarchar, @lastEndTime, 121)
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the MSDN Books Online documentation for [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) - it has a complete list of all supported, built-in date formats that you can use with CONVERT.

E.g.

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 100)
```

will convert today's date and time to a string in the format `mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)`.

If your string does not match any of those formats, then you either have to

- use `DATEPART` function to extract bits and pieces of your DATETIME and concatenate that together manually
- use SQLCLR and the .NET DateTime function to do it in a SQL-CLR user-defined function
- don't do it in SQL Server and pass back the DATETIME to the calling client and let the caller handle the conversion to the actual presentation format

Answer (score 3):

Really horribly, to get a precise format you have to use the [datepart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function and build it up.

```
select datepart(yyyy, @lastEndTime) + '-' + datepart(mm, @lastEndTime) + '-' + datepart(dd, @lastEndTime) +' ' + datepart(hh, @lastEndTime) + ':' + datepart(mm, @lastEndTime) + ':' + datepart(ss, @lastEndTime) + '.' + datepart(ms,@lastEndTime)
```

You could define it as a [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) for ease of use though.

Edit - as someone has pointed out, this format happens to be a standard - ODBC canonical so

```
 CONVERT(CHAR(23), @lastEndTime, 121)
```

should do it.

Comment: yeah, that does. Fortunately, you don't have to do that for the above  ODBC canonical format.

Comment: good point @andras - this is 121 I think.  I got so used to doing odd formats I always did it manually (which is obviously evil when it comes to performance).  Shall update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE @lastEndTime datetime
set @lastEndTime = getdate()

select convert(varchar,@lastEndTime,121)

For more style
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @jfrobishow: a one-off error here, I guess. The variant with milliseconds is `121`.